# Excel - changing embeeded DSN

Tags: excel, dsn

I have an Excel with an embeeded DSN. When I open the Excel in Notepad i see it:

`DSN=serverName;Description=serverName;UID=UserName;;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=LT-533571;DATABASE=DatabaseName`

I want to change the server property, how can I do it? It's driving me nuts, tried editing the excel in Notepad - crashes the Excel, tried some basic VBA, but I was only able to edit connection properties of pivot tables, and not change the DSN.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the Excel version, but in 2003 the data source(s) in a workbook can be changed by going to `Data`>`Import External Data`.

This however uses an interface from around the time we descended from the trees, Microsoft Query - not very user friendly.  I recommend Rob van Gelder's excellent [Query Editor](http://vangelder.orconhosting.net.nz/excel/queryeditor.html) add-in which removes much of the pain in managing data connections in Excel.

Edit: In 2007 I gather the DSN can be changed via `Data tab`>`Properties` (in Manage Connections Group)

Comment: Link to QueryEditor is dead.